# Is short-circuiting in assignment statements considered good style?

Tags: python

If I understand correctly

```
myvar = a and b or c
```

gives the same result as

```
if a:
  if b:
    myvar = b
  else:
    myvar = c
else:
  myvar = c
```

so I guess it's more elegant.

I seem to remember seeing this kind of short-circuit assignment statement in JavaScript code. But is it considered good style in Python to use short-circuiting in assignment statements?

Comment: The things you'd use this for in Javascript generally aren't as much of a concern in Python.

Comment: I frequently use `a = b or c` but for more complicated forms I would probably write something more clear.

Comment: @user2357112 could you give an example?

Comment: @FogleBird do you mean that the second code example in the question is probably more sensible that the first?

Comment: @KnewB: You don't have as much need to detect whether objects support certain methods, and when you do, you generally catch the `TypeError` or `AttributeError`. `foo.bar` won't give `undefined` in Python if `foo` doesn't have a `bar` attribute.

Comment: @user2357112 +1 ah I see the difference -Python's exceptions vs. JS's `undefined` -and because `undefined` is falsy the boolean logic works. Perhaps I should start a new question for this but, why the less of a need in Python (and more need in JS) to detect whether objects support certain methods?

Comment: You don't need to detect whether the user's Python interpreter supports `''.join` before you use it.

Comment: @user2357112 as a means of feature detection, I see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really an opinion question, but for the most part, the answer is no. It goes against multiple style guides, probably because people tend to think it means "if a is true, use the value of b, otherwise use the value of c" rather than the real meaning, which is what you posted.

You probably want the new-ish conditional expression syntax instead:

```
myvar = b if a else c
```

Answer (score 13):

Most of the time, you then want to use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) instead:

```
myvar = b if a else c
```

Short-circuiting is very Pythonic however, just be aware of the pitfalls where `b` is false-y; using short-circuiting will result in *different* result in that case. Most of the time, you do *not* want to assign `c` instead.

Even in that case, you can still get the same result with an adjusted condition:

```
myvar = b if a and b else c
```

Short-circuiting is great for defaults:

```
foo = somevar or 'bar'
```

or for making sure pre-conditions are met:

```
foo = somevar and function_raises_exception_if_passed_empty_value(somevar)
```

Comment: This is not quite equivalent to the expression the OP gave. `b=0` will result in `myvar=c` in the OP's version, whereas here `myvar` will get the value of `b`.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: Exactly. Most of the time that is *not* what you want.

Comment: But the OP's second example seems to make clear that that is what he wants in this case, no?

Comment: @HenryKeiter: No, it shows the OP understands the expression quite well, which is rare. I made it more explicit that a conditional expression is better in *most* cases, *because* most people are *not* aware of the problem.

Comment: easy enough `b if a and b else c` ... now i think it is equiv